# Multivariate Normal Distribution: Divide each random variable by its standard deviation

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, covariance-matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution, marginal-distribution

If $X$~$Normal(\mu,\Sigma)$, and I divide each random variable in $X$ (the marginals) by its standard deviation, what will happen to the covariance matrix $\Sigma$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, let's say $X=[X_1,...,X_n]$, and your new vector is $Y=[X_1/\sigma_1, ...,X_n/\sigma_n]$. For each pair $i,j$, the new covariance entries will be
$$(\Sigma_Y)_{ij}=\operatorname{cov}(X_i/\sigma_i, X_j/\sigma_j)=\frac{\operatorname{cov}(X_i,X_j)}{\sigma_i\sigma_j}=\frac{(\Sigma_X)_{ij}}{\sigma_i\sigma_j}$$

Note that, the diagonal entries will all be $1$ (assuming no degenerate entries exist).